# Can't compile C++11 source using GCC 5.1 toolchain

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc5

I'm trying to compile a library written with C++11 features using GCC 5.1 on Ubuntu. However, it complains `std::unique_ptr` is not defined.

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 5.1.0
g++ (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 5.1.0
```

CXX flags:

```
-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic
```

Output:

```
error: ‘unique_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
         std::unique_ptr< detail::RegexImpl > m_pimpl;
```

However, I'm able to compile the exact same code on OSX.

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
```

CXX flags:

```
-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the source.  Are you including `<memory>`?

Comment: I had no problem with gcc 5.1 on Ubuntu. I compiled it from source, added the includes and lib path to env variable and it works.

Comment: It sounds like you are relying on the implementation-dependent inter-header dependencies.  No surprise when non-portable code breaks when you try to port it, luckily the fix is easy.

Comment: BTW I'm sad that GCC says the misleading "template type".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, it would be nicer to see something like "error: 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not exist" here. That would require some extra work on the part of the GCC devs if the error message is shared between the "does not exist" and the "does exist but is not a template" cases, though.

Comment: @hvd: Well just changing it to "template" would be a start :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't realise that was what you meant. :) Yeah, the standard uses "class template" and "function template". Neither "template type" nor "type template" is a standard term, but "type template" is better in line with the standard's terms. (Or, after your edit, just "template" works too.)

Comment: I've reviewed the source, and indeed the <memory> include was missing. I assumed it was there because the code compiles fine with Clang. I'm not the author of the library so I can't comment on inter-header dependencies, but is this the cause?

Comment: @Thijs Yes. A library header `A` may include library header `B` for pretty much any reason. If you need library header `B`, but only include library header `A`, then it may work on some implementations, and fail on others. And even libc++ has such silently included headers.

Comment: @hvd: Yeah plenty of people get confused as to what templates really are, an in part IMO that's because compilers and books and poor tutorials say silly things like "template class" as if that's some magical kind of class. You and I know that that's not the case. If they knew that it instead is a _template_ that makes a class, perhaps they'd have an easier time of it. :) Anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The library's source is missing an `#include <memory>`.

This is simply an unfortunate error by the author of the library. It's surprisingly commonplace for people [to rely on certain standard headers *just so happening* to include other standard headers on their particular implementation](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-6-an-inclusion-pitfall/), without checking that they're using all the `#include` statements that they should.

You could hack the `#include` in for now but, long term, you should raise a bug with the library author and maybe even contribute a patch, if the project accepts patches.

Comment: Is there a compiler known to use the minimal inclusions necessary?  Or is the best strategy for that library's maintainer just to make sure it uses multiple c++ compilers in order to find errors like this one?

Comment: @BrianCain: I'm not really sure how to answer that, to be perfectly honest. My personal strategy is one of _diligence_: whenever I write a standard library name that I don't absolutely know I've already used in the same translation unit, I look up which header it comes from and I then add the relevant `#include` if it's not already there. Can't really go wrong if you keep that up, though it does get a little tedious after a while.

Comment: Got it! Will submit a patch to the author

Comment: @BrianCain: (Of course, that doesn't always work; on the occasion that I forget all steps other than the first, sometimes my build breaks and that's great, but other times it does not and then I have just introduced one of these silent bugs. -.-)

Comment: Thank you so much @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Saved me a lot of debugging.